# Is it possible to get back original password using the hashed result and the salt parameter of the pbkdf2.pbkdf2Sync() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, pbkdf2

I am implementing password authentication for my webapp, and I was wondering if it is safe to have the salt parameter hard coded? In the many tutorials that I have seen, they randomly generate the salt, but I can't do that if I want to compare the input password to the actual password. My concern is that someone could extract my actual password from using its hashed form with the salt parameter.

Comment: I dont know anything about the specific function you are asking but "hash" means one way. If something is properly hashed it is not possible to get a password from it short of guessing every possible password in existance which can literally take millions of years or (A LOT) longer depending on the password. You should not hard code the hash and you should not compare plain-text passwords. You should rehash and compare the result.

Comment: Hey Marie, thanks for your answer. If I should not hard code the hash (in my case it's a env variable), then how do I store it in order to compare the password that the user inputs to the correct password?